# How to set Timeout for httpwebrequest in windows phone 8 app?

Tags: windows-phone-7, httpwebrequest, windows-phone-8

i am developing an windows phone 8 app , in my app i am calling services and downloading some data into my app .

i am using httpwebrequest for request, but i am not able to set timeout to my httpwebrequest object.

This is how i have created and used my httpwebrequest :-

```
public async Task<string> ServiceRequest(string serviceurl, string request, string methodname)
        {
            string response = "";
            try
            {

                var httpwebrequest = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(serviceurl)) as HttpWebRequest;
                httpwebrequest.Method = "POST";
                httpwebrequest.Headers["SOAPAction"] = "http://tempuri.org/" + iTestservice + "/" + methodname + "";
                httpwebrequest.ContentType = "text/xml";


                byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(request);
                using (var requestStream = await Task<Stream>.Factory.FromAsync(httpwebrequest.BeginGetRequestStream, httpwebrequest.EndGetRequestStream, null))
                {
                    await requestStream.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
                }

                response = await httpRequest(httpwebrequest);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                return null;
            }

            return response;

        }

        public async Task<string> httpRequest(HttpWebRequest request)
        {
            string received;

            using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)(await Task<WebResponse>.Factory.FromAsync(request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse, null)))
            {
                using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (var sr = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                    {

                        received = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
                    }
                }
            }

            return received;
        }
```

**My Doubt is :-**

1) How can i set timeout property to Httpwebrequest ??

2)What are the different ways in which i can set the timeout property in my windows phone 8 app ??

Please let me know .

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't use `HttpWebRequest.Timeout` on Windows Phone because it doesn't exist for that platform.

If you're open to using a beta library, you could install [`HttpClient` via NuGet](https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http) and use *its* `Timeout` property.

Otherwise, you're probably best off to use `TaskEx.Delay`, which is part of [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async). After installing that library, you would replace this line:

```
response = await httpRequest(httpwebrequest);
```

with this:

```
var httpTask = httpRequest(httpwebrequest);
var completeTask = await TaskEx.WhenAny(httpTask, TaskEx.Delay(5000));
if (completeTask == httpTask)
  return await httpTask;
else
  return null; // timeout
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why TaskEx.Delay() and not Task.Delay()?

Comment: `Task.Delay` doesn't exist in Windows Phone.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HttpStatusCode.HttpStatusCode is an enum which can be used to get the type of error in HttpWebRequest.

`catch(WebException ex)`
`{`

```
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;
```

`if(response.StatusCode==HttpStatusCode.GatewayTimeout)
{
}`

`}`

The GatewayTimeout indicates that an intermediate proxy server timed out while waiting for a response from another proxy or the origin server.For more information you can refer to the [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode(v=vs.110).aspx)
site for this.Hope it helps