# Windows Phone 8 HttpWebRequest Timeout

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, timeout, windows-phone-8

Just a philosophical question here...
I consider Timeout in an asynchronous HttpWebRequest something basic, something so basic I can't even think why would it not be implemented...
I tried to make a basic Windows Phone 8 app today. Something that would use REST service from a given server to fetch some JSON. So I create HttpWebRequest just to realize that on WP8 there is no way to timeout it! I looked around, found people hacking solutions together, having lots of errors, lots of problems, producing flaky solutions and dirty code.

[One topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15038875/how-to-set-timeout-for-httpwebrequest-in-windows-phone-8-app)
[Another here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpdevelop/thread/9d15cb94-38c0-43fa-bb76-9635c81c457a#53f06848-ae36-4333-a037-4b021a1edd37)
[Yet one more...](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpdevelop/thread/8523abc9-4b78-4d6e-bed0-1e729810bc1e)
[And even more](http://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post/2012/04/09/Timeout-of-HttpWebrequest-and-WCF-service-calls-on-Windows-Phone.aspx)

All because of what? I do not understand Microsoft's reasoning behind the decision to remove such basic option/functionality. Am I missing something, or Microsoft is just being dumb with WP8?

Comment: As in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15038875/how-to-set-timeout-for-httpwebrequest-in-windows-phone-8-app/15041383#15041383) Microsoft has introduced the HttpClient for both WP7.1 and WP8. It provides a better API plus it supports what you need and also supports compression among other things.

Comment: Hmm didn't spot that little link, thanks :)

Comment: it doesn't support compression