# How to implement timeout and retry while accessing a web service before throwing an error?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, connection-timeout, timeoutexception

I am developing a WP8 application. I created a web service on out-systems and then I am calling those web service methods in my app:

```
ServiceReference1.WebServiceClient ws = new WebServiceClient();
ws.FetchInboxAsync(EmailId);
```

Now what I want is 10 seconds timeout while trying to access the web service and retry 3 times before throwing an error but I am not sure how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

WebServiceClient is no standard class which exists in WP8. You will have to provide details about the connection layer you are using.

I assume you are ussint httpWebRequest for the connection. In this case, you can view this thread for details on how to define the timeout.
After 3 timeouts you will then have to return an exception or error message.

[How to set Timeout for httpwebrequest in windows phone 8 app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15038875/how-to-set-timeout-for-httpwebrequest-in-windows-phone-8-app)

Comment: I have created a web service on out-systems with the name `WebService` which contains few methods e.g `FetchInbox`. Now I added its link as service reference (named as `ServiceReference1`) on Visual studio. This is how I get the class `WebServiceClient` in `ServiceReference1` namespace which I use to call the WebService methods. This is it as far as connection layer is concerned. Unlike your assumption, I don't use httpWebRequest.

Comment: Then what communication class is used to do the actual communication? We do not know how your code looks inside.